# Preserving order when you can't format right

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a function to document some settings in a word doc and to make the information in the document easy to read I need to preserve the order of the properties of the original object. Unfortunately this means I can't 'format right'.

```
$o = [PSCustomObject]@{
    number = 1
    fruit = 'Orange'
    Clothing = 'Shirt'
    Colour  = 'blue'
}

$p = $o | get-member -type NoteProperty | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

foreach ($n in $p) {
    Write-Output "$n $($o.$n)"  #this line is actually function to write a line into the word doc taking $n and $($o.$n) as parameters
}
```

The part of the code which has the issue is '$o | get-member -type NoteProperty' as Powershell reorders the list at this point.  I'm not sure that my approach is correct.

This function will actually be a recursive function to walk an object tree and output the results.  Any ideas on a new approach or to correct my original approach would be very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
 $p = $o.psobject.Properties | select -ExpandProperty Name
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean by

> format right

But since PowerShell 3 you can create ordered hashtables:

```
[ordered]@{
    number = 1
    fruit = 'Orange'
    Clothing = 'Shirt'
    Colour  = 'blue'
}
```

Comment: Format right, means to apply the formatting/sorting in powershell at the last possible moment.

I can't use an ordered hashtable as the original object will contain nested objects and you can't add an object to an array with +=.  ( can post this code snippet if you think it would be helpful)

If I took the array approach, I'd need to convert all downstream objects to ordered arrays and the recurse through them.  This is probably doable, but would really complicate the code.